# JPA Hibernate Persist any Enum (a Map key) in human readable format?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, dictionary, enums

Say you have a class which needs to save some mapped items, using any Enum for the key. Using this mapping it generates e.g. `varbinary` (SQL Server) with a hexadecimal value.

```
@Entity
public abstract class X {
    @ElementCollection
    private Map<Enum, Boolean> values;
}
```

This works but the main issue is readability. The data in the database isn't human readable. trying to use `@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)` or with EnumType.Ordinal doesn't work since the Enum can be any type and that saves the `MyEnum.SOME_VALUE` as "SOME_VALUE".

Is it possible to intercept the save/retrieve and save a fully qualified name (com.x.myenum.value) or something legible which could be used to restore the enum instead of a hexadecimal value?

Answer (score 3):

To store a Map where key is an enum, and get something human readable in db you could try:

```
@Entity
public class QuestionnaireDefinition{
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "questionnaireDefinition", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "language", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private final Map<Language, QuestionnaireDefinitionTranslation> translations = new HashMap<Language, QuestionnaireDefinitionTranslation>();
... }
```

where QuestionnaireDefinitionTranslation is the entity or value that will be fecthed given the Language enum.
In this example the map value is type: QuestionnaireDefinitionTranslation

```
@Entity
public class QuestionnaireDefinitionTranslation {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)    
    private Language language;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private QuestionnaireDefinition questionnaireDefinition;

    private String text;
    ...
}
```

The class Language is an ordinary enum:

```
public enum Language {
    EN, ES, FI, FR;
}
```

The idea to make this work is:
1. First persist a the owner class:

```
QuestionnaireDefinition questionnaireDef = new QuestionnaireDefinition();
em.persist(questionnaireDef );
```

and then the aggregated class using your enum as key.

```
QuestionnaireDefinitionTranslation translation = new QuestionnaireDefinitionTranslation();
translation.set(questionnaireDef);
translation.setLanguage(Language.En);
translation.setText("hello");
em.persist(translation);
```

voilá that's all, you can fetch known by your enum

```
QuestionnaireDefinition qd = em.find(1,QuestionnaireDefinition.class);
qd.getTranslations().get(Language.EN);
```

Be aware with transactions, LazyException and that stuff.