# Allowing users to add their own custom fields in a Spring MVC Hibernate application - What's an ideal approach?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

We all may have seen applications like JIRA, or many CRM or other applications that allow its users to define their own custom fields to an entity, and do a variety of stuff with it, like making them mandatory, validate their values and so on.

I want to do just that in the Product we are creating.

Let's assume our product allows a user to create his/her own Project. A project has pre-defined attributes such as

- Name (String)
- Description (CLOB)
- Type (String)
- Owner (String)
- Status (String)

Now, as a user, I would like to add the following custom field to my project

- Due Date (Date)

Ideally he should be able to create a custom field in my product which would capture the following details:

- Name of the field
- Type of the field
- Default Value
- List of values (if the field is to be a drop down list)
- Mandatory or not

Similarly, I would like to allow this feature of adding custom attributes not only to a project, but to a few other entities as well.

This is the technology stack we're using and so far we're pretty ok with it.

- Spring MVC, JSP and jQuery as the Web Framework and for the Views
- JPA with Hibernate for persistence
- Oracle, MS SQL, MySQL - Currently our product works on these databases.

How do I approach this requirement? I would like to be educated on the following:

- How to I decide the best data model for this? Do I add a separate table for custom field definitions, and another one for their values, and associate them to my entity by means of a foreign key?
- What should I do in my JSP/JS Layer to dynamically paint a screen with whatever custom fields that are defined?
- How do I let Spring MVC and Hibernate handle all this data model and the views?

I have read a couple of questions here, specifically this

[Adding custom fields in my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383924/adding-custom-fields-in-my-application)

Reading this, I could figure out I could use NoSQL databases to achieve this functionality. While I could do that, I want to know if there's any way I can achieve this in my current technology stack so as not introduce something new at this stage of my product evolution.

I'm extremely sorry if my question is not framed or worded properly. I'm relatively new to these technologies, and would like to learn with each challenge.

Thanks,
Sriram

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Collection mappings](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html) in order to save different attributes based on different users. Saving extra fields as map where attribute-name will be the KEY and attribute-value will be VALUE of the map.

```
@ElementCollection
Map<String, String> data;
```

Also, you may want to keep the key of the map to be an Enum then you should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908525/jpa-hibernate-persist-any-enum-a-map-key-in-human-readable-format) out where an `Enum` has been maintained as the key and that `Enum` is kept in an another entity which is the value of that key-value pair.
E.g.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "valueEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@MapKeyColumn(name = "fieldType", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private final Map<FieldType, ValueEntity> otherFields = new HashMap<>();
```

Here field type is an `Enum`.

Comment: Thank you. Using Collection Mappings, I can save different attributes based on different instances of an entity. However, this brings me to another issue. What will I do about data types? I would want my user to be able to add a Date field, or a numeric field and so on. Now how do I design my data model to handle all data types?

Comment: @sriramsridharan Then you'll need to have one more column to save the datatype of the data getting saved and based on that datatype you can do whatever manipulations you need to do However, I would rather suggest you to checkout some NoSQL databases.